# Bump function's support

Tags: general-topology, analysis

How does this function (for instance) have compact support, if the support is the open interval (-1,1) ?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function

Answer (score 3):

The support of a function $f$ is the *closure* of the set where it is non-zero,

$$\operatorname{supp} f := \overline{\{ x : f(x) \neq 0\}},$$

so the support of a function is by definition always closed. The closure of $(-1,1)$ is the compact interval $[-1,1]$.